# Check the elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I would like to check the elements of the vector

```
    x = c(0.0153, 0.1352, 0.2820, 0.4629, 0.6944, 0.8919,
          1.0638, 1.2458, 1.4068, 1.5969, 1.7700, 1.9024,
          2.0144, 2.1143, 2.2286, 2.3453, 2.5096, 2.7499,
          3.0299, 3.5061)
```

is between the elements of the vector

```
    y =c(0.0000, 0.0917, 0.2174, 0.3087, 0.4151, 0.8984,
         1.0921, 1.1579, 1.3803, 1.3806, 1.6234, 1.8682,
         2.0565, 2.2194, 2.285, 2.4183, 2.4463, 2.512,
         2.7964, 3.0766, 3.5061)
```

which means that is the first element of vector `x` between the first and second elements of the vector `y` or not, ... but not checkig the last element `x`.

Is there anymethod to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could probably remove the for loop

```
x[(x>y[-length(y)])&(x<y[-1])]
```

and add the last x value. Im not clear if you want the last x or not?

or

```
x[!((x-y[-length(y)])*(y[-1]-x)<0)]
```

if you want the last x

Comment: I do not want to check the last element of x. The first code I think is correct.